# How to highlight a DataGridView row or make it glow temporarily?

Tags: c#, datagridview

Using a C# DataGridView how can I:

1. Highlight a row
2. Make a row glow temporarily (go yellow for a couple of seconds)

Comment: Temporarily in the sence, when you select the row or by default.

Comment: You can do 1 by selectedrowstyle for grids but what do you intend by **glow row temporarily**

Comment: @Craig, you forgot to say **now**. I see you accepted 9 answers after my previous comment.

Answer (score 24):

In order to simulate the user selecting a row, use

```
myDataGrid.Rows[n].IsSelected = true;
```

as Gabriel has suggested.

In order to temporarily color highlight a row in a DataGridView control, set the `DefaultCellStyle.BackColor` property to a color of your choice for the row you are interested in.  Then enable a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` control for the time period of your choice.  When the timer's `Tick` event fires, disable the timer and set the row's `DefaultCellStyle.BackColor` back to its original color.

The short example below is for a WinForm application that has a DataGridView named GlowDataGrid, a timer named GlowTimer, and a button named GlowButton.  When clicking on GlowButton, the third row of the DataGridView glows yellow temporarily for two seconds.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // initialize datagrid with some values
        GlowDataGrid.Rows.Add(5);
        string[] names = new string[] { "Mary","James","Michael","Linda","Susan"};
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            GlowDataGrid[0, i].Value = names[i];
            GlowDataGrid[1, i].Value = i;
        }
    }

    private void GlowButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // set third row's back color to yellow
        GlowDataGrid.Rows[2].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        // set glow interval to 2000 milliseconds
        GlowTimer.Interval = 2000;
        GlowTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void GlowTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // disable timer and set the color back to white
        GlowTimer.Enabled = false;
        GlowDataGrid.Rows[2].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
    }
```

Comment: Should be Selected instead of IsSelected

Answer (score 4):

**My Code to you**

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.Interval = 500;
        t.Enabled = false;

        dataGridView1.CellMouseEnter += (a, b) =>
        {
            if (b.RowIndex != -1)
            {
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[b.RowIndex].Cells[0];
                dataGridView1.Rows[b.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
                dataGridView1.Rows[b.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.Black;
                t.Tick += (c, d) =>
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[b.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Blue;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[b.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.White;
                    t.Enabled = false;
                };
                t.Enabled = true;
            }
        };
        dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Col1", "Col1");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Col2", "Col2");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Row1", "Col1");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Row1", "Col2");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Row2", "Col1");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Row2", "Col2");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Row3", "Col1");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Row3", "Col2");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Row4", "Col1");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Row4", "Col2");
    }
```

Comment: Did you got your answer. If yes please share it, it may help someone else

Answer (score 1):

Use like

```
gridLibrary.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow
```

to set the color, then you will need to reset the colors after the
grid is sorted.

Then using the timer to change the highlight color after delay.

```
gridLibrary.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.white
```

Comment: (i) should be [i] C# question

Answer (score 0):

You can highlight 'n' row by someDataGridView.Rows[n].IsSelected = true;

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `GridView` `AutoFormat` property.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            int index = e.RowIndex;
            DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[index];
            row.Selected = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is using AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor and RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor properties on dataGridView, setting the BackColor on a Row will override these style values.
Therefore use Color.Empty instead of Color.White to reset the BackColor to its default value, thus restoring the AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle and RowsDefaultCellStyle values.

```
dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Empty;
```